# Proving $\left|\begin{smallmatrix} b^2+c^2 & ab & ac \\ ba & c^2 +a^2 & bc\\ ca & cb & a^2+b^2\end{smallmatrix}\right|=4a^2b^2c^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, symmetric-polynomials

I am attempting to prove the following expression, using elementary row and column operations. I have included the attempted solution.

> $$\det \begin{bmatrix} b^2+c^2 & ab & ac \\ ba & c^2 +a^2 & bc\\ ca & cb & a^2+b^2\end{bmatrix}=4a^2b^2c^2$$

---

**Attempted Solution**:

$$\begin{matrix} R_{1}\to aR_{1}\\ R_{2}\to bR_{2}\\ R_{3}\to cR_{3}\end{matrix}\mapsto   \det\begin{bmatrix}b^2+c^2 & a^2 & a^2\\ b^2 &c^2+a^2 & b^2 \\ c^2 &c^2 &a^2+b^2\end{bmatrix} \tag1$$ $$\begin{matrix}R_{1}\to R_{1}-(R_{2}+R_{3})\mapsto \det\begin{bmatrix}0 &-2c^2 &-2b^2 \\ b^2 &c^2+a^2 &b^2 \\ c^2 & c^2 &a^2+b^2\end{bmatrix}\end{matrix}\tag2$$ $$\begin{matrix}R_{2}\to c^2R_{2}-b^2R_{3}\end{matrix}\mapsto \det\begin{bmatrix}0 &-2c^2&-2b^2\\ 0 & c^4+a^2c^2-b^2c^2 & c^2b^2-a^2b^2-b^4\\ c^2 &c^2 &a^2+b^2\end{bmatrix}\tag3$$

---

I seem to have made some mistake in the transformation $(3)$. Any pointers as to why this transformation is invalid are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Wow I don't think I had ever seen a matrix in the title of a post, or even realized that was possible!

Comment: I don't think I follow what happened in Step 1.

Comment: if you do a row operation you need to update the det. for example, multiplying a row by a, in this case, will multiply the det by a^3

Comment: You could easily see that the determinant is a polynomial $p(a,b,c)$ of degree $6$ in $a,b,c$.  Observe that $a=0$, or $b=0$, or $c=0$ makes the determinant $0$ (two rows will be linearly dependent).  Note also that $a\mapsto -a$ doesn't change the determinant.  Therefore, $p(a,b,c)=ka^2b^2c^2$ for some constant $k$.  Then, $p(1,1,1)=4$ implies $k=4$.

Comment: Ms. Sarrus already did this for you and [found out that this rule  holds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus)

Comment: What means $R_{1}\to aR_{1}$? if it means "multiply row 1 by a", then you have two problems: multiplying row 1 by a will change the determinant of the matrix. And you didn't actually multiply your matrix by a but changed row 1 in a very strange and improper way.

Comment: Why do you accept an answer that does not solve you problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation you did in step $(3)$ actually involves two steps: $$R_2 \mapsto c^2 R_2 \\ R_2 \mapsto R_2-b^2 R_3$$

So, you have to divide by $c^2$ to preserve the identity of the determinant.